# superposition analysis technique

Tags: circuit-analysis, analysis

Below I am presented with the following circuit and asked to solve for the current through R1:

***EDIT:*** in the diagram below I made a mistake, V2 is shown as 8V, it is supposed to be 40 V.

[image]

I apply a source transformation (ST) on R5 and V2 to get:

[image]

Then I combine R11 and R12 to get:

[image]

Then I apply another ST on R16 and I2 to get:

[image]

Finally, I add R20 and R21 to get :

[image]

Then I continue to solve by trying an ST on the I4 and R25 to get a DC voltage and the 30 ohm in series with the rest of the components. Then I write a KVL to solve for the overall loop current but I get the wrong value. Where have I gone wrong in my procedure?

**Second Edit:***
Here I have tried some of the suggestions (which I had already previously attempted) that I am showing:

I will now call this point A:

[image]

Going from A to B thru an ST:

[image]

Going from B to C by combining the 20 and 30 ohm:

[image]

Then I write the KVL:
-6 +4i + 12i + 32 = 0

Solving for i = -1.65 A. However, when I run a sim on the original circuit I started with, I am showing 825 mA as shown below:

[image]

Comment: In your first ST on R5 and V2 how did you get 8A for the current source?

Comment: Sorry, the first diagram V2 is supposed to be 40V

Comment: Ok. At ST on R16 and I2 the current source must change to voltage source. But you didn't..

Comment: Youre right. another error in the diagram, however on paper i changed it to a 32 V source and was still getting the wrong answer.

Comment: What is your answer?

Comment: I edited my original post by adding the rest of my analysis and comparing it to a simulation result. Answers still don't match.

Comment: You need to be a little more thorough with your source transformation: you need transform both the source type and the source amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting your edit, which changes the \$V_2\$ voltage value, look at the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnUwF0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can go directly from \$A\$ to \$D\$ by simply using a voltage divider approach. But, following your conversion first to Norton, then applying the two resistors in parallel, and then converting back to Thevenin (\$A\to B\to C\to D\$) gets you to the same place. (Notice how these magnitudes differ from yours.)

At this point, I might do this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX2Pqj.png)</sup>

From here it is easy to compute the current in \$R_1=\frac{6\:\text{V}-19.2\:\text{V}}{4\:\Omega+12\:\Omega}=-825\:\text{mA}\$, where the green arrow shown is the conventional current direction.

Comment: You have enough reputation that you probably don't care about down votes, so I will just beg you not to provide complete homework solutions like this. I am afraid that the site will be overrun with homework questions, and cheating in school will be just that much easier.

Comment: I agree with you, but it is not a homework problem. Just a problem I happened to come across on an incomplete video from youtube.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Writing me, as you just did, is the best way to affect what I do. (I never did care for the point system here.) That said, please pop over here and read the comment between this and yours by CircAnalyzer. The OP wrote a great deal and I felt that deserved something in response. Besides, I'm no policeman and don't want to be one here. Not my job. And there are dozens of others who may be helped by walk-through answers. That, to me, is more important. (Keep in mind I've taught 2nd and 3rd yr courses at the largest university in my state. I have firm opinions about this.)

Comment: @jonk, I have edited my post to include the rest of my analysis. I have also shown the result of a simulation which does not appear to match. Still confused.

Comment: @CircAnalyzer I'll add my OWN simulation to show you my analysis is correct. You'll see it added, shortly.

Comment: so am i wrong then? if so, where? why is my analysis inconsistent with sim result?

Comment: @CircAnalyzer No, I mean your simulator result is crazy. I don't know why it is giving you that value. Except that I see a 40 V voltage supply where I used to see an 8 V supply. When you just make up numbers like that, you get nutty results.

Comment: Yeah that was supposed to be 40V from the start.i drew the diagram wrong but made a note about it in my post. I just did not edit the diagram

Comment: @CircAnalyzer Well, I guess I wasted a lot of my time because I missed that point. My apologies for not reading better. Where did you happen to say that? (Oh. I see. "EDIT:")

Comment: no worries. you are here trying to help.

Comment: @CircAnalyzer I'll take the time to adjust my response, then. Or simply delete it. I don't want an incorrect answer floating about. Which would you prefer?

Comment: whatevers easier for you.

Comment: @CircAnalyzer Okay. I fixed it.

Comment: from F to G, how did you get a 19.2V DC supply?

Comment: @CircAnalyzer In the same way that going from A directly to D gets its value. Don't you see the voltage divider (two resistors and a voltage source?) Do you know how to Thevenize that, directly? To get the Thevenin voltage I took 32 V and multiplied it by 30 Ohms divided by the sum of 20 Ohms and 30 Ohms to get 19.2 volts. The Thevenin resistance is just 20 Ohms parallel to 30 Ohms.

Comment: is it because you cant just combine the 20 ohm and 30 ohm in parallel to end up with a series circuit with the 32V, 6V, 4 ohm and a potential 12 ohm like I have in part C of my analysis?

Comment: @CircAnalyzer I could take the LONG route and go through the Thevenin to Norton, parallel resistors combination, and then back from Norton to Thevenin. I show that process in A->B, B->C, and C->D. But I also show you that you can go directly from A->D if you use the Thevenin equivalent for a resistor voltage divider without all that effort. It's a LOT easier. But yes, you can go through the LONG WAY AROUND THE BARN, if you want to.

Comment: i am still unclear about why I cant go from B to C in my analysis. where i combine the 30 and 20 ohm resistor, but leave the 32 V there.

Comment: nevermind i see it now. thanks for all your help. that was very useful